# Functional test throws SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] Connection refused

Tags: 8, testing

I have a phpunit.xml file which works for me for Kernel Base tests and which allows me to connect to a SQLite database. I want to use it for Functional tests also. I am new to Functional tests. My phpunit.xml file looks like this:

```
<phpunit bootstrap="./core/tests/bootstrap.php" colors="true"
         beStrictAboutTestsThatDoNotTestAnything="true"
         beStrictAboutOutputDuringTests="true"
         beStrictAboutChangesToGlobalState="true"
         printerClass="\Drupal\Tests\Listeners\HtmlOutputPrinter">

  <env name="PHP_IDE_CONFIG" value="PHPSTORM"/>

  <php>
    <!-- Set error reporting to E_ALL. -->
    <ini name="error_reporting" value="32767"/>
    <!-- Do not limit the amount of memory tests take to run. -->
    <ini name="memory_limit" value="-1"/>
    <!-- Example SIMPLETEST_BASE_URL value: http://localhost -->
    <env name="SIMPLETEST_BASE_URL" value="http://intellipass:8888/"/>
    <!--Example SIMPLETEST_DB value: mysql://username:password@localhost/databasename#table_prefix -->
    <env name="SIMPLETEST_DB" value="sqlite://localhost//sites/default/files/db.sqlite"/>
    <!-- Example BROWSERTEST_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY value: /path/to/webroot/sites/simpletest/browser_output -->
    <env name="BROWSERTEST_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY" value="/tmp"/>
  </php>

  <testsuites>
    <testsuite name="Intellipass Functional Test Suite">
      <directory>./modules/custom/intellipass/tests/src/Functional</directory>
    </testsuite>
  </testsuites>

</phpunit>
```

And my Functional test class looks like this:

```
<?php

namespace Drupal\Tests\intellipass\Functional;

use Drupal\Tests\BrowserTestBase;

class EncryptionSecretTest extends BrowserTestBase {

  /**
   * Modules to install.
   *
   * @var array
   */
  public static $modules = ['system', 'intellipass'];

  protected function setUp() {
    parent::setUp();
  }

  /**
   * Tests comments in book export.
   */
  public function testRedirect() {
    $authenticatedUser = $this->drupalCreateUser();
    $this->drupalLogin($authenticatedUser);
  }

}
```

I am execution the test by the following command:

```
./phpunit-4.8.9.phar --testsuite="Intellipass Functional Test Suite"
```

Then I am getting this error:

```
peter@NB32 intellipass (master) $ ./phpunit-4.8.9.phar --testsuite="Intellipass Functional Test Suite"
PHPUnit 4.8.9 by Sebastian Bergmann and contributors.

E

Time: 3.73 seconds, Memory: 10.00Mb

There was 1 error:

1) Drupal\Tests\intellipass\Functional\EncryptionSecretTest::testRedirect
Exception: PDOException: SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] Connection refused
Drupal\Component\DependencyInjection\PhpArrayContainer->createService()() (Line: 79)


/Users/peter/DevPrivat/intellipass/core/lib/Drupal/Core/Test/HttpClientMiddleware/TestHttpClientMiddleware.php:44
/Users/peter/DevPrivat/intellipass/vendor/guzzlehttp/promises/src/Promise.php:203
/Users/peter/DevPrivat/intellipass/vendor/guzzlehttp/promises/src/Promise.php:156
/Users/peter/DevPrivat/intellipass/vendor/guzzlehttp/promises/src/TaskQueue.php:47
/Users/peter/DevPrivat/intellipass/vendor/guzzlehttp/promises/src/Promise.php:246
/Users/peter/DevPrivat/intellipass/vendor/guzzlehttp/promises/src/Promise.php:223
/Users/peter/DevPrivat/intellipass/vendor/guzzlehttp/promises/src/Promise.php:267
/Users/peter/DevPrivat/intellipass/vendor/guzzlehttp/promises/src/Promise.php:225
/Users/peter/DevPrivat/intellipass/vendor/guzzlehttp/promises/src/Promise.php:62
/Users/peter/DevPrivat/intellipass/vendor/guzzlehttp/guzzle/src/Client.php:131
/Users/peter/DevPrivat/intellipass/vendor/fabpot/goutte/Goutte/Client.php:155
/Users/peter/DevPrivat/intellipass/vendor/symfony/browser-kit/Client.php:312
/Users/peter/DevPrivat/intellipass/vendor/behat/mink-browserkit-driver/src/BrowserKitDriver.php:144
/Users/peter/DevPrivat/intellipass/vendor/behat/mink/src/Session.php:148
/Users/peter/DevPrivat/intellipass/core/tests/Drupal/Tests/BrowserTestBase.php:333
/Users/peter/DevPrivat/intellipass/core/tests/Drupal/Tests/BrowserTestBase.php:472
/Users/peter/DevPrivat/intellipass/modules/custom/intellipass/tests/src/Functional/EncryptionSecretTest.php:17
/Users/peter/DevPrivat/intellipass/vendor/phpunit/phpunit/src/Framework/TestCase.php:764
/Users/peter/DevPrivat/intellipass/vendor/phpunit/phpunit/src/Framework/TestResult.php:612
/Users/peter/DevPrivat/intellipass/vendor/phpunit/phpunit/src/Framework/TestCase.php:724

FAILURES!
Tests: 1, Assertions: 1, Errors: 1.
```

The SQLite file definitely exists. I have tried the relative and absolute path.

How can I fix this

> Exception: PDOException: SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] Connection refused

error?

Comment: The test cannot connect to your database; either because your database is not running, it does not accept connections (firewall?) or your path is not right (I'd expect it to look like `sqlite://sites/default/files/db.sqlite`, but have very little experience with sqlite).

Comment: Firewall or path cannot be the problem. Does anyone use functional tests with sqlite or uses them in mysql on a mac environment with mamp and can post example config?

Answer (score 1):

I have found the solution. Drupal tries to use my default DB connection at first. This connection does not work for the test. Therefor I have placed an if-case around my DB-connection in my settings.php file. Then the DB connection in my phpunit.xml file will be used.

I have extended the testing documentation at https://www.drupal.org/docs/8/phpunit/phpunit-browser-test-tutorial for this (scroll down to the SQLite headline).